# Document methods defined using Simple JavaScript Inheritance

Tags: javascript, netbeans, code-completion, jsdoc

I'm defining classes using [John Resig's Simple JavaScript Inhertance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) and documenting them with JSDoc's [`@lends`](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagLends) and [`@constructs`](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagConstructs) annotations, but NetBeans doesn't provide code-completion. This works with modules I've defined using [namespace](https://github.com/jweir/namespace) because I'm referencing them directly. Here's an example of a simple class:

```
MyClass = Class.extend(
    /** @lends MyClass.prototype */
    {
        /** @constructs */
        init: function () {
            console.log('init');
        },

        foo: function () {
            console.log('foo');
        }
    }
);

var c = new MyClass();
c.  <-- ctrl-space only shows built-in methods like hasOwnProperty() and toString()
```

Does anyone know a way to document these classes so code-completion is available in NetBeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetBeans does not support `@lends`, `@constructs`, `@memborOf` or similar tags still. They are set for 7.4 and 8.0 but I don't believe they will be implemented soon since they are reported from 7.0 or so. The second of two [workarounds](https://bugzilla-attachments-224729.netbeans.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=130093) will work with `Class.extend()` by first assigning the (previously) anonymous object containing the methods to the class.

**Prototype**

```
/** @class */
var Canine;
Canine = function() {};
Canine.prototype = props;

/** @type Canine */ var canine = new Canine();
```

**Anonymous Object**

```
/** @class */
var Feline = {
    purr: function() { console.log('meow'); },
    fall: function() { console.log('landed on feet'); }
};
Feline = create(Feline);

/** @type Feline */ var feline = new Feline();
```

Note: This works even without the `@type` comment in NetBeans 7.4 patch 1.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version (as of this writing) is [NetBeans 7.3 Beta 2](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/73/). It has support for JavaScript auto-completion, and debugging. It will also work in Chrome and provides round-trip updates between NetBeans and Chrome. You should see if this will help you with your JavaScript development work.